# Are there some pitfalls in my spark structured streaming code which causes slow response after several hours running?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

The spark job has the correct functions and logic. However, after several hours running, it becomes slower and slower. Are there some pitfalls in the below code?

```
val query = "(select * from meta_table) as meta_data"    
val meta_schema = new StructType()         
       .add("config_id", BooleanType)         
       .add("threshold", LongType)         
var meta_df = spark.read.jdbc(url, query, connectionProperties)         
var meta_df_explode=meta_df.select(col("id"), from_json(col("config"), meta_schema).as("config")).select("config_id", "thresold", "config.*")  

//rules_imsi_df: joining of kafka ingestion with the meta_df_explode 

//rules_monitoring_df: static dataframe for monitoring purpose   

val rules_monitoring_stream =        
            rules_imsi_df.writeStream           
                        .outputMode("append")  
                          .format("memory")
                        .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("120  seconds"))
                         .foreachBatch {                  
                              (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
                                    if(!batchDF.isEmpty)                                                     {    

printf("At %d, the microbatch has %d records \n", Instant.now.getEpochSecond, batchDF.count())                                                             
batchDF.show()                                                            
 batchDF.persist()                                                                var batchDF_group = batchDF.groupBy("id").sum("volume").withColumnRenamed("sum(volume)", "total_volume_id")                  
rules_monitoring_df = rules_monitoring_df.join(batchDF_group, rules_monitoring_df("id") === batchDF_group("id"), "left").select(rules_monitoring_df("id"), batchDF_group("total_volume_id")).na.fill(0)                         
rules_monitoring_df = rules_monitoring_df.withColumn("volume", rules_monitoring_df("volume")+rules_monitoring_df("total_volume_id"))                                                               batchDF.unpersist()                                                                          }                                          }.start()    


      while(rules_monitoring_stream.isActive)    {                  
Thread.sleep(240000)                      
... //Periodically load meta data from database          
meta_df = spark.read.jdbc(url, query, connectionProperties)              
meta_df_explode=meta_df.select(col("id"), from_json(col("config"), meta_schema).as("config")).select("config_id", "thresold", "config.*")         
}
```

Comment: why are you using - ```.format("memory")``` , It is only for debugging purpose - ```This should be used for debugging purposes on low data volumes as the entire output is collected and stored in the driver’s memory. Hence, use it with caution.```

Comment: Thanks Srinivas. Good finding. Yeah, I forgot removing this part after testing. Besides this issue, are there any more issues that I should pay attention to? Thanks!

Comment: can you please add your application logic what actual you are doing ??

Comment: Thanks. The basic logic is quite simple. I want to to stream the kafka data in 120 seconds window, process the microbatch data and populate a static dataframe (rules_monitoring_df). To get the microbatch, the ingested data from kafka will be joined together with a meta dataframe, which is periodically read from the postgre database. The microbatch will be accumulated by summing some data fields into the static dataframe. There are also some logic in the while loop to reset some rows in the static dataframe if some conditions met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below points are my observation from the above code. I will add incase if I find anything.

1. Remove `format("memory")` as its for debugging purpose not for production use case.
2. Remove all `var` from the code.
3. Don't assign `DataFrame` back to `rules_monitoring_df` inside `foreachBatch` as this `foreachBatch` will be invoked by multiple threads at the same time, You might get wrong results. Instead try to save result into hdfs or hive table & read back whenever you need.
4. Try to move below code to `spark streaming listener` if possible & avoid extra `while` loop.

```
while(rules_monitoring_stream.isActive)    {                  
Thread.sleep(240000)                      
... //Periodically load meta data from database          
meta_df = spark.read.jdbc(url, query, connectionProperties)              
meta_df_explode=meta_df.select(col("id"), from_json(col("config"), meta_schema).as("config")).select("config_id", "thresold", "config.*")         
}
```

Comment: thanks mate, it is very very helpful! I will further improve it according to your comments.

Comment: One more question. As in my use case, I need to update the existing records in rules_monitoring_df inside foreachBatch, not just insert the new records. To save into hive table is a good idea. Does spark sql support update records in hive table now? I tried this approach in spark 2.4.0, and found update statement is not supported. What will be the best work around for this case? thanks!

Comment: where & how are you going to use data from ```rules_monitoring_df``` dataframe ? I mean apart from ```foreachBatch``` function

Comment: In the while loop, I will use it to write to a postgresql table if some conditions met. In addition, some rows will be reset for this dataframe under some conditions.                                                      In addition, I tried to remove the format(memory). It does not show OOM issue now. However, after several hours running, it generates a node unhealthy error. "1/2 local-dirs are bad: /mnt/yarn; 1/1 log-dirs are bad: /var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers"

Comment: Inside while loop code you can move to inside query progress listener.. as this code is not depedning on dataframe